# Cpython UnicodeError is thrown when passing char to string Python object [solved]

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I am trying to pass a `char` variable to a str object using [PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize).

### Problem

Something weird happens when passing the uninitialized `char *` variable to the function mentioned above. Raised `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte` exception when calling a function similar to `unquote(var) # var = "%E2%84%A2"` ( hope that makes sense), As you already know the `var` variable is a string that is encoded to a URL path `(eg, urllib.parse.quote)`, so I implemented my own function to decode the encoded url `(eg, urllib.parse.unquote)` in C for Python, I had to debug the code and it works fine, The problem is when using `PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize` to return the value and I understand that it is an invalid byte sequence, however when I had debugged the sequence (`printf("result of char: %i", string[index])`) I noticed that values ​​is equivalent to `print("™".encode())` and it works fine when you use `print("™".encode().decode())` however in Cpython it doesn't. Lastly when I use [PyBytes_FromStringAndSize](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html#c.PyBytes_FromStringAndSize) it returns a very different value `b"\xe2.2\x84"`

### Edit 1: Example Code

```
static PyObject *unquote(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
        const char *s;
        Py_ssize_t l;
        Py_ssize_t n = 0;
        PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s#", &s, &l);
        for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                if (s[i] == '%') {
                        n += 1;
                        i += 2;
                }
        }
        if (n == 0) {
                return PyUnicode_FromString(s);
        }
        Py_ssize_t req = l - 2 * n;
        char *t = malloc(req);
        for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                if (s[i] == '%') {
                        t[i] = (hexint(s[i + 1]) << 4 | hexint(s[i + 2]));
                        printf("C: ord: %i\n", t[i]);
                        i += 2;
                } else {
                        t[i] = s[i];
                }
        }
        return PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize(t, req);
}
```

##### Python:

```py
>>> from urllib import parse
>>> import module
>>> var = parse.quote("™")
>>> module.unquote(var)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

### Edit 2: Debugging

Consider this simple little block of code:

```py
from urllib import parse
import module


utf8python = "™".encode()  # utf-8
for x in utf8python:
    print(f"Python: ord: {x}")

module.unquote(parse.quote("™"))
```

##### Out:

```
Python: ord: 226
Python: ord: 132
Python: ord: 162
C: ord: 226
C: ord: 132
C: ord: 162
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    module.unquote(parse.quote("™"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

### Edit 3: Solution (basically a nonsense that took me 5 days to solve)

Remember this code block from the minimum reproducible example

```
for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                if (s[i] == '%') {
                        t[i] = (hexint(s[i + 1]) << 4 | hexint(s[i + 2]));
                        printf("C: ord: %i\n", t[i]);
                        i += 2;
                } else {
                        t[i] = s[i];
                }
        }
```

The memory of `t` was made to measure `req`, the problem is that we are skipping unassigned indexes because when decoding in the case of mod the indexe skips 2 times. Making the next time allocate on an index of `t` dependent on `i` thus producing random characters because it's ram junk, Now the index to allocate on `t` is independent.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where the code says `return PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize(t, res);`, where does `res` come from? Did you mean `req`? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and make sure that everything in your program has the values you expect, at the times you expect, by stepping through with a debugger - especially on the C side.

Comment: Also: did you consider the implications of doing `i += 2;`, when `i` is **also** your index into the *destination buffer*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks! I already made the correction in the example code, I just typed quickly the code and missed some errors. I've also debugged the value left on line 18 and compared it to the python encoding and it's similar.

Comment: Which line is line 18?

Comment: "Lastly when I use `PyBytes_FromStringAndSize` it returns a very different value `b"\xe2.2\x84"`" Yes, exactly as I expected. The `\xe2` and `\x84` bytes come from the original data (they are part of the UTF-8 encoding for the character). The `.` and `2` are uninitialized garbage in the `malloc`d buffer, due to how the `i += 2` is used. Using the string method fails because a `\xe2` byte isn't part of a valid utf-8 encoding sequence due to the intervening garbage. You probably also have undefined behaviour from a buffer overrun.